# How can I create a lookup table of different procedures in nim?

Tags: nim-lang

In python, functions are "first class citizens" and can be passed to functions/methods as arguments.

Let's say I wanted to start writing a basic remote procedure call(rpc) library in python, I might start by creating a dictionary that maps the function names to the actual function objects:

```
rpc = {}  # string: function


def register_rpc(name, function):
    """ Register a function as a RPC """
    rpc[name] = function


def sum_nums(a, b):
    """ Sum numbers """
    return a + b


register_rpc("sum_nums", sum_nums) # register sum_nums as RPC

print(rpc["sum_nums"](10, 15))
```

I can get close to this in Nim.  The issue is I have to explicitly define the arguments and argument types for the `proc` in the lookup Table, and this has to match the `register_rpc` procedure's definition as well.  Here is my *semi-equivalent* Nim code:

```
import tables


var rpc = initTable[string, proc(a, b: int): int]()  # explicitly defined procedure arguments/types


# Procedure arguments/types must match Table's proc definition or else I can't register a RPC
proc register_rpc(p: proc(a, b: int): int, n: string): bool =
    #[ Register a function as a RPC ]#
    rpc[n] = p
    true


# proc definition matches Table/register_rpc
proc sum_nums(a, b: int): int =
    #[ Sum numbers ]#
    a + b


discard register_rpc(sum_nums, "sum_nums")
echo rpc["sum_nums"](10, 15)
```

Is there any way to create a `register_rpc` procedure where I don't have to explicitly define the `proc` arguments and their types?  How can I make my `Table` match this as well?  I asked a question, that seems semi-related, yesterday:

[Can I unpack `varargs` to use as individual procedure call arguments with nim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68186716/can-i-unpack-varargs-to-use-as-individual-procedure-call-arguments-with-nim)

However I am unable to use `untyped` types for the `Table`.

Will I have to overload the `register_rpc` procedure to cover all my different `type` scenarios?  How do I create a lookup table without having to explicitly define the `proc` arguments/types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dynamic way of handling things is not supported in nim. Type of procs has to be known at compile time, that's just a fact. Though of course you can do something so horrible and unpleasing like:

```py
import tables

var table = initTable[string, pointer]()

table.add("add", cast[pointer](proc(a: int, b: int): int =
  a + b
))

table.add("negate", cast[pointer](proc(a: int): int =
  -a
))

assert cast[proc(a: int, b: int): int {.cdecl.}](table["add"])(10, 20) == 30
```

But lets be honest here, if you accidently cast to a wrong proc, you are doomed. We need safety in this case, a way to differentiate the pointer. That's where abstraction comes in.

```py
import macrocache, options

const counter = CacheCounter("counter")

func typeID(tp: type): int =
  const id = counter.value
  static: counter.inc
  id

{.pragma: dynProc, cdecl, noSideEffect, gcsafe, locks:0.}

type
  DynamicProc* = object
    id: int
    value: pointer

func initDynamicProc*[T](p: T): DynamicProc =
  DynamicProc(id: T.typeID, value: cast[pointer](p))

template ID*(d: DynamicProc): int = d.id

func get*(d: DynamicProc, tp: type): Option[tp] =
  if tp.typeID != d.id:
    none(tp)
  else:
    some(cast[tp](d.value))

var safeTable = initTable[string, DynamicProc]()

safeTable.add("add", initDynamicProc(proc (a, b: int): int {.dynProc.} =
  a + b
))

assert safeTable["add"].get(proc (a, b: int): int {.dynProc.}).get()(10, 20) == 30
assert safeTable["add"].get(proc (b: int) {.dynProc.}) == none(proc (b: int) {.dynProc.})
```

Its still verbose but this time you have guarantee its safe. `dynProc` pragma is needed to fix the type matching as type with different pragmas is considered different type.